# Dojo Custom Build 1.6 into a single file

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I've a problem trying to create a custom build on Dojo, I dont even know is it possible what I want..

I want to have a "single js file" loading all the components that i use across the application. so it doesnt load several files just one containing what I need, or at least just the ones I need.

As far as I read I need to create a Profile for this build, this is the profile I use (file in profiles folder ex: test.profiles.js).

```javascript
dependencies ={
  layers:  [
      {
      name: "test_dojo.js",
      customBase: true,
      selectorEngine: "acme",
      dependencies: [
            "dojo/dojo",
            "dijit.form.Form",
            "dijit.form.Button",
            "dijit.form.Textarea",
            "dojo.parser",
            "dijit.form.MultiSelect",
            "dijit.layout.ContentPane",
            "dijit.layout.BorderContainer",
            "dijit.Toolbar",
            "dijit.form.TextBox",
            "dijit.form.SimpleTextarea",
            "dijit.form.ComboBox",
            "dojo.date",
            "dojo.date.locale",
            "dijit.form.DateTextBox",
            "dijit.layout.TabContainer",
            "dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore",
            'dijit.Dialog',
            "dojox.grid.DataGrid",
            "dijit.form.DropDownButton",
            "dijit.form.CheckBox",
            "dijit.form.FilteringSelect",
            "dijit.form.NumberTextBox",
            "dijit.Tree",
            "dojox.charting.Chart2D",
            "dojox.charting.widget.Legend",
            "dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip",
            "dojox.charting.action2d.Magnify",
            "dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.green",
            "dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.red",
            "dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.blue",
            "dojox.widget.Standby",
            "dojox.form.Uploader",
            "dojox.form.uploader.plugins.IFrame",
            "dojox.form.uploader.FileList",
            "dijit.ProgressBar",
            "dojox.embed.Flash",
            "dijit.Tooltip",
            "dojox.cometd",
            "dijit._base.scroll"
      ]
      }
  ],
  prefixes: [
      [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
      [ "dojox", "../dojox" ]
  ]
};
```

I ran it this way: 
 **> build.bat profile=test action=release**

this generates me the folder "release" inside if this I find dojo -> dojo, dijit, dojox folder and inside dojo -> test_dojo.js

I copy the content of the release into the application and replace the script tag in the html files.

```html
<script src="/dojo_release/dojo/test_dojo.js" type="text/javascript" 
djconfig="usePlainJson: true,parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

but get the error: "dojo is not defined in line 14"

and if I try to load the dojo and then this file:

```html
    <script src="/dojo_release/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript" 
djconfig="usePlainJson: true,parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script src="/dojo_release/dojo/psirt_dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I debug the application and get that is trying to load several files (as it used to)  and get errors such as "Could not load 'dijit.form.Form'; last tried '../dijit/form/Form.js'"

this maybe a basic question im quiet new with dojo and more with the custom build stuff.

Do I have correct the profile or what could be the problem here, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the 'customBase' flag to do this. You can simply override the dojo.js file with its current contents _plus some cached modules of your own.

```
dependencies ={
  selectorEngine: "acme",
  layers:  [
      {
      name: "../dojo/dojo.js",
      dependencies: [
         ...
      ]
  }
}
```